# Asp.net Core3.1 SignalR Hub Consuming lot of memory, giving Out of Memory exception and terminating WebSocket connection

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

The SignalrHub Consuming lot of memory . On search on google I find out that

**SignalR uses a fixed-size ring buffer to hold messages (so old messages are only removed when space is needed) in order to allow messages to be replayed to clients that reconnect. You can modify this buffer size using the IConfigurationManager.DefaultMessageBufferSize option.**

But I didn't find any options to set this **DefaultMessageBufferSize** option in **Asp.Net core 3.1**

[GitHub signalr issue Link](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/4159)

Following are the nuget package used in the project

[image]

So Is there anyway we can set up the **DefaultMessageBufferSize** In Asp .net Core Signalr.

If not what are the alternatives in Asp .net core 3.1 for this?

Comment: DefaultMessageBufferSize does not exist in ASP.NET Core SignalR, and there is no equivalent because ASP.NET Core SignalR doesn't use a ring buffer or hold onto messages. You should capture a dump and do some analysis to figure out what is using memory.

Comment: Thanks @Brennan for your input. can you tell more about how the memory allocation happen inside the hub in Asp .net core Signalr